# SQL generic way of copying table schema

Tags: sql, database

Is there a generic way of copying the structure of a table to a new table?
By generic I mean a command that is supported in different types of sql databases (e.g. MS SQL, MySql, ...)

i heard about that one:

```
CREATE TABLE db.mynewtable LIKE db.myoldtable;
```

but as far as I know this is MySQL specific

Comment: The only thing that is defined in the SQL standard ist: `create table new_table as select * from old_table` if you add `where 1 = 0` to the select, this will only create the table structure, not the data. You can do `create table .. LIKE ..` in Postgres as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you! Where did you get this information from? Did you buy the standard and read it? Or is there any other source?

Comment: is there a way to enhance this to let it copy the primary key setting from the original table too?

Comment: No, not in a DBMS independent way.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * INTO tablename 
  FROM oldtable
  WHERE 1 <> 1
```

This will create a new, empty table with the same structure

Comment: That's not standard SQL